# How to make React call `mark` less often?

Tags: reactjs, performance

I’m trying to investigate the performance of a large React app, but every time I try the regular performance tool in Chrome, a very large proportion of it is taken by the `mark` function, which I assume is the `Performance.mark` Javascript function, see the following image as an example. Here, out of 140ms, 108ms were spent in the `mark` function. [image: performance graph]

Is there a way to make React not put so many marks? I know I can compile in production mode, but then hot reload does not work which makes it a lot harder to iterate quickly.

Answer (score 1):

One way to remove the performance marks from react in the performance tab is to override the performance.mark method like this:

```
window.performance.markOrig = window.performance.mark;
window.performance.mark = (name, options) => {
  // ignore react internal marks
  if (name[0] !== "⚛") {
    window.performance.markOrig(name, options);
  }
};
```

This way you'll see only your perf marks and it should clean up the timings when in development mode

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your situation correctly, the goal is "make React do less work," and all of the development-time `mark` calls are a symptom of React doing too much work. Have you tried using the React Dev Tools' [profiler](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html)? This is a standard feature of the React Developer Tools browser extension (e.g., [in Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)) and will tell you which of your React components and rendering options is making React do so much work (versus Chrome's standard profiler, which merely tells you *that* React is doing so much work).

**Edit**: With that said, it appears that the time reported by `mark` is actually taken up by the React Developer Tools extension itself. If you disable that extension, the time it takes should go away.

Comment: Well, no, it's not about making React do less work, it's about getting useful information when profiling. I know very well React's profiler, but it doesn't help when profiling what happens outside React. And no, calling `mark` is not "React doing work", it's just noise.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie - Sorry I can't be more help. In my experience, if the performance problems / high CPU usage are coming from React, then I see a bunch of React noise in Chrome's profiler, but the React Developer Tools profiler shows which components are a problem, and if the problems / high CPU are coming from something other than React, it's clear enough in Chrome's profiler. I've not seen where React code takes so much CPU that it overwhelms Chrome's profiler and yet is not a performance problem itself. (Although it does appear to be possible to make `mark` take less time - see my edit.)